# Setting up aws ses with django site hosted on elastic beanstalk

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, django-anymail

I am attempting to use amazon ses to send user verifcation emails for a django site deployed using elastic beanstalk.

I have allauth managing the user sign up, and using anymail to manage the emails.

I have successfully completed the DKIM setup at namecheap (who host the domain)

I am receiving a permission related error though, any advice appreciated:

```
AnymailAPIError at /accounts/signup/
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the SendRawEmail operation:
User `arn:aws:sts::873836696822:assumed-role/aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role/i-0ce34e11fac257334' 
is not authorized to perform `ses:SendRawEmail' on resource `arn:aws:ses:us-west-2:873836696822:identity/newuser@testing.com'

botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the SendRawEmail operation:
User `arn:aws:sts::873836696822:assumed-role/aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role/i-0ce34e11fac257334' 
is not authorized to perform `ses:SendRawEmail' on resource `arn:aws:ses:us-west-2:873836696822:identity/newuser@testing.com'
```

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot/text showing the permissions given to the `aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role` role from the IAM console? Link should be: https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home?#/roles/aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role

Comment: Temporarily attach the `AmazonSESFullAccess` managed AWS IAM policy to the role and retry - does that fix the issue?